# UIAlertController Detached View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6.1, uialertcontroller

Sometimes when I create a UIAlertController and present it in an if-statement, I get the the warning `Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged.` How do I circumvent that warning? Is there something different I can do in calling & presenting the UIAlertController? Should I use something different then putting the UIAlertController in a if-statement?

```
if(!defaults.boolForKey("hasLaunchedOnce")) {
        updateSettingsLabel.hidden = false
        var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Instructions", message: "Sample Text", preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) {
            (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        }

        alert.addAction(okAction)

        presentViewController(alert, animated: true,completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Wasn't your problem that you tried to run it from ViewDidLoad (not the if statement)? At least that was my problem in a similar case.

Answer (score 6):

You should present the `UIAlertController` in `viewDidAppear()` or somewhere after the view has shown. The view hierarchy is not ready before `viewDidAppear()`, so presenting another view before that may be problematical.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped.

Answer (score 0):

try doing your presentViewController like this:

```
self.view.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: When I do that, the view controller isn't presented at all.